# I can not see the error in the Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i bought book with ready-made apps. One of them didn't work, after click the button, app just got a crash. 
I had hopes i wil see in "Event log" in Android Studio what is wrong with app, but i see only:

```
13:58   Gradle sync started

13:58   Gradle sync completed

14:11   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

14:11   Gradle build finished in 4s 582ms
```

How can I check what is wrong with the application?

Comment: To debug your code we will need to see your code and some error log output. What you have shown is the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are looking at the Gradle **Event Log**, instead of the **Android Monitor**.

In Android Studio, on the Top Menu `View` -> `Tool Windows` -> `Android Monitor` should do the trick.